# TFX / Tensorflow Data Validation (TFDV) throws overflow encountered in float_scalars error

Tags: tensorflow-data-validation

Following basic tutorial, and trying to generate stats for a TFRecord, I get a overflow error:

```
import tensorflow_data_validation as tfdv
stats = tfdv.generate_statistics_from_tfrecord(data_location='/path/tfrec-train-00067-of-00100')

Error:
basic_stats_generator.py:221: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in float_scalars
  self.sum_of_squares += v * v
```

The dataset is audio examples (float32) <=17sec and associated labels.

Is there something different that needs to be done to handle these types of examples?

Comment: I implemented a work-around by initializing the v variable into float128:  
    v = np.float128(0.0)
before the "for v in value:" loop.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed [(GitHub commit)](https://github.com/tensorflow/data-validation/commit/20273e96786d2d4887f7408f657a9e3eee61d3af).